# Node with Passport: Compare Password throws error undefined is not a function, when it returns return done(null, user);

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have read all the related questions and responses and still can't fix this issue. Please see the code below and help me understand why terminal is throwing 'undefined is not a function'. 
For a rundown of the functions: 
The query section looks up SQL gets the users PW from DB. Parse results gets just the pw and eliminates the 'key' from the key value pair. Move pw function is there just as a buffer so that compare PW will not execute until we have retrieved the pw to compare with.

I have been stuck on this for a while, any help is much appreciated. To see the running app, go here...a working un/pw combo are user5 1234, but bc of the error it will look up username, password, verify that its a match (the compare pw and the look up pw functions actually do work and tell you if its a existing pw and un combo, but when i try and return done(user, null) to the passport login route, it crashes...

https://[redacted].com/

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var db = require('../database');
var returnedPw;
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');


var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 's',
    user : 'n',
    password : '',
    database : 's'
});
//stripped credentioals

// Include User Model
var User = require('../models/user');
// Include Student Model
var Client = require('../models/client');

// Include Instructor Model
var Company = require('../models/company');

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users/signup');
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    // Get Form Values
    console.log('starting post and making new user');

    var first_name      = req.body.first_name;
    var last_name       = req.body.last_name;
    var street_address  = req.body.street_address;
    var city            = req.body.city;
    var state           = req.body.state;
    var zip             = req.body.zip;
    var email           = req.body.email;
    var username        = req.body.username;
    var password        = req.body.password;
    var password2       = req.body.password2;
    var type            = req.body.type;

    // Form Field Validation
    req.checkBody('first_name', 'First name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('last_name', 'Last name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email must be a valid email address').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('users/signup', {
            errors: errors,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            street_address: street_address,
            city: city,
            state: state,
            zip: zip,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password2: password2
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            email: email,
            username:username,
            password: password,
            type: type
        });
        console.log('calling post to database file to receive new user:' + newUser)

        // THIS IS WHERE WE ARE POSTING THE NEW USER TO THE DATABASE!!!
        db.postUsers(newUser);

        var newClient = new Client({
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            address: [{
                street_address: street_address,
                city: city,
                state: state,
                zip: zip
            }],
            email: email,
            username:username
        });
        if(type == 'client'){
            //User.saveClient(newUser, newClient, function(err, user){
            //  console.log('Client created');
            ///}); works but replacing w sql
        } else {

        var newCompany = new Company({
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            address: [{
                street_address: street_address,
                city: city,
                state: state,
                zip: zip
            }],
            email: email,
            username:username
        });  
            //works but replacing w sql
            //User.saveCompany(newUser, newCompany, function(err, user){
            //  console.log('Company created');
            //});

            //sql save function

            console.log('calling sql save..');
            //db.postUsers(newUser, newClient);

        }

        req.flash('success','User added');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});


<!--//// -USER AUTH SECTION- \\\\--!><!--//// -USER AUTH SECTION- \\\\--!><!--//// -USER AUTH SECTION- \\\\--!>

/*
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
}); */


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});


router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/', failureFlash:'Wrong Username or Password'}), function(req, res){
    req.flash('success','You are now logged in');
    var usertype = req.user.type;
    res.redirect('/'/*+usertype+'s/classes' */);
});



passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done ) {
            console.log('in users the username is ' + username)

            connection.query('SELECT password FROM t_user WHERE username = ?', username, function(err, user) {
                parseResults(user, done);
            });// end query


        function parseResults(user, done) {   
            Object.keys(user)[0];
            var key = Object.keys(user)[0];
            user[key]; 
            var storedPw = user[key];
            for(var i in storedPw){
                returnedPw = storedPw[i];
            }

            console.log('returnedPw is defined here ' +returnedPw);
            movePw(returnedPw, done);
        }// end function

        var candidatePassword = password;


        function movePw (returnedPw, done) {
            if (returnedPw ) {
                User.comparePassword(candidatePassword, returnedPw, function(err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    if(isMatch) {
                        //return done(null, user);
                       // req.flash('success','User Access Granted');
                       //console.log('go head')
                        user = username;

                       return done(null, user);
                        //done(null, user);
                       //notifyOuterScope();
                        //return true;
                    } else {
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        // Success Message
                        req.flash('failureFlash','User Access Denied. False Password');
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
                    }
                });  
            }

            else {console.log('return PW not defined')}
        }

    }// end outer function ?

));//end passport


// Log User Out
router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    // Success Message
    req.flash('success', "You have logged out");
    res.redirect('/');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
      return next(); 
    }
  res.redirect('/')
}

/* COMPARING PASSWORDS */

    /* where are we returning the password from the user db profile?


        bcrypt.hash('mypassword', 10, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) { throw (err); }

            bcrypt.compare('mypassword', hash, function(err, result) {
                if (err) { throw (err); }
                console.log(result);
            });
        });

    */

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: write an answer to your question, that way it would help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a working example of using SQL and passport.js with node. I was having difficulty using the Local Strategy required for passport (using sql commands instead of mongodb commands that you see in most passport documentation), and it turns out the reason is because I wasn't passing the correct variables/ was also passing in unnecessary variables.

I corrected it above. Instead of using the User.FindOne Mongo db query in local strategy, this is an example of how to do the same username/ password querys using SQL, within passport local strategy. There isn't much documentation on using SQL and passport / node.